# Connecting to MSSQL 2008 With JAVA JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

im trying to create a connection to the MSSQL08 database on my computer :

this is my simple piece of code :

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {


    String userName ="username";
    String password ="password";

    String url ="jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=Lando";

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

i get this Error :

> SEVERE: null java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=Lando  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)  at
>   javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:34)

when i change the URL to this : "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=Lando"
then i get this Error :

> SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by
>   this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides
>   support for JDBC 4.0. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment
>   (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the
>   sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.  at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.(SQLServerConnection.java:304)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1011)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)  at
>   javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:34)

I added the sqldjbc4.jar file to the project libraries in neatbeans, i also set the CLASSPATH in enviroment variables to the directory of the Microsoft Driver.
what could be the problem ?

Comment: Did you remove the old sqljdbc.jar from the classpath too?

Comment: yes, tried that too, same result.

Comment: Be sure only `sqldjbc4.jar` in your classpath and use url `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=Lando`

Comment: Most applications don't use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. Make sure you add it to the classpath (and maybe also buildpath) of your application!